# How to parse semicolon-delimited lines of text in a csv file with fgetcsv()

Tags: php, csv, text-parsing

I'm trying to read a CSV file and turn it into an array like this.

```
$h = fopen("onderdelen-test.csv", "r");

echo '$parts = array(';

if($h) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        foreach ($data as $num) {
            $part = explode(';', "$num");

            echo "array('partid' => '$part[0]', ";
            echo "'descr' => '$part[1]'), ";
        }
    }
    fclose($h);
}

echo ')';
```

The csv looks like this

```
123456 ; partdescription
234567 ; partdescription, anotherdescription
345678 ; part, description and some other description
```

The problem is that it also explodes on commas and not only on the semicolon.
I've tried adding quotes around the description but did put some weird questionmarks around the description that I could not get rid of.

Edit 1: 
If I used the semicolon as delimiter in the fgetcsv function, then I can't retrieve the values by key, it just starts another loop everytime a semicolon is found.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php 3rd parameter - $delimiter

Comment: @ineersa love the way you are killing many of the fastest guns in the west :)

Comment: @ineersa added my take on that at the bottom, I tried this but it start a new loop everytime

Comment: PS: You dont have to wrap variables in double quotes `$part = explode(';', $num);`

Comment: PPS: You can just build an array and then `print_r($part);` and get a visual representation of that array, you dont have to contrive the output like you are

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah I know but I want to loop through it and do executes some queries. So I use this as a middle step to check if the array gets build correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping it simple as all you are trying to do is see what is produced from this input before progressing on to bigger things

```
123456 ; partdescription
234567 ; partdescription, anotherdescription
345678 ; part, description and some other description
```

This code, note I have added the third parameter to the `fgetcsv`

```
<?php
$h = fopen("onderdelen-test.csv", "r");

if($h) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) {
        print_r($data);
        echo "partid = " . trim($data[0]) . "\n";
        echo "descr  = " . trim($data[1]) . "\n";
    }
    fclose($h);
}
```

Produces this output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] =>  partdescription
)
partid = 123456
descr =  partdescription
Array
(
    [0] => 234567
    [1] =>  partdescription, anotherdescription
)
partid = 234567
descr =  partdescription, anotherdescription
Array
(
    [0] => 345678
    [1] =>  part, description and some other description
)
partid = 345678
descr =  part, description and some other description
```

Comment: I tried every `foreach` possibility I know but nothing retrieves the data correctly. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I mean I need to loop through the array and execute some queries but when I use a normal `foreach` and then try value[key] I don't get the value that I need

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your echo's. That's works perfectly thanks! I guess I was just overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple snippet to parse csv files:

```
    $i=0; $keys=array(); $output=array();
    $handle=fopen("onderdelen-test.csv", "r");
    if ($handle){
        while(($line = fgetcsv($handle,0,';')) !== false) {
            $i++;
            if ($i==1) {
                $keys=$line;
            } elseif ($i>1){
                $attr=array();
                foreach($line as $k=>$v){
                    $attr[trim($keys[$k])]=$v;
                }
                $output[]=$attr;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    //$output here is your data array
```

Here you will get associative array from csv file with keys from 1st line of file.

```
    id ; description
123456 ; partdescription
234567 ; partdescription, anotherdescription
345678 ; part, description and some other description
```

Resulting array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123456 
            [description] =>  partdescription
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 234567 
            [description] =>  partdescription, anotherdescription
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 345678 
            [description] =>  part, description and some other description
        )

)
```

Your `echo` thing is kinda really wrong.

Comment: You might like to de-method that to make it easier for a beginner to understand, specially as OP is not using a class

Comment: @RiggsFolly feel free to edit if got any improvements. Removed function declaration.

Comment: That also produces a wierd output. You might want to test it. It looses one of the input rows

Comment: Or maybe you added a title row in row 1 and you are skipping it, sorry my mistake. Although the OP's input file does not have a title line??!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried this but yeah the input is really weird. I need it to be `[0] => partid, [1] => descr`

Comment: Edited with test result, also added code to trim keys. Warning 1st line need to be keys.